# Canon LPB2900B Not Working in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: printing, canon

I have a Canon LBP2900B in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit
The printer automatically configures when switched on, but when print command is given,it shows

> ccp send_data error, exit

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [the guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190#Ubuntu_12.04_Install).

For me it worked only with 32bit ubuntu 12.04.